# Why does drawImage's scaling add borders?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

Solved: toggeling the property [imageSmoothingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) of the canvas' context to false stops these lines from appering
Note: the property seems to toggle itself back to true on resize and simmilar and thus has to again be set to false

I'm not so sure if "borders" is the right term, but anyway:
My problem is that if I try to (up)scale a tile from a tile atlas, it adds parts of the tiles next to it.

My tile drawing code is as follows:

```
ctx.drawImage(tileAtlas, s.x, s.y, s.w, s.h, d.x, d.y, d.w, d.h);
```

s is the source and d the destination. The calculation for the destination's width and height is the source's multiplied by the scalar.

```
const d = {
            ...
            w: s.w *scalarX,
            h: s.h *scalarY
}
```

The end result for scaling by two look like this:

[image: canvas scaled by two]

The tileset:

[image: the tileset]

The lines appear for every tile that is (up)scaled and for every upscaling I tried (1.25, 1.5, 2, 5, 10, ...) only 1, 0.75, 0.625, 0.5, 0.375, 0.25 and so on worked.

The size of the tiles is not the problem, here these are 64x64.
I also checked if the wrong positions have been given to s or d but they align to the upscaled tilesize of 128x128 that the destination shall have.

Here as a snipped, I scaled down the code as much as possible.

```js
const canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

const tileAtlas = new Image();
tileAtlas.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdcQg.png"; //path to the tile atlas file; here the img in the post

const tiles = {
  width_x: 64,
  height_y: 64,
  scalar: 1
}
const canv = {
  width_x: 4, //size in tiles
  height_y: 4
}

var aa = true; //the anti-aliasing, thanks Chris G!

/* applies canv to the canvas and clears it */
function applyCanvas() {
    const sizeX = canv.width_x * tiles.width_x * tiles.scalar;
    const sizeY = canv.height_y * tiles.height_y * tiles.scalar;
    canvasElement.setAttribute("width", sizeX);
    canvasElement.setAttribute("height", sizeY);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = aa;
}

/* draws the tile in tile atlas at tx, ty
 * to the canvas at cx, cy
 * the canvas cordinates are based on the tilesize
 */
function drawTile(tx = 0, ty = 0, cx = 0, cy = 0) {
  const s = {
    x: tx * tiles.width_x,
    y: ty * tiles.height_y,
    w: tiles.width_x,
    h: tiles.height_y
  };
  const d = {
    x: cx * s.w * tiles.scalar,
    y: cy * s.h * tiles.scalar,
    w: s.w * tiles.scalar,
    h: s.h * tiles.scalar
  };
  ctx.drawImage(tileAtlas, s.x, s.y, s.w, s.h, d.x, d.y, d.w, d.h);
}

/* draws the canvas full of the tile at tx, ty
 * and changes the scaling
 */
function fillWithScaler(tx = 0, ty = 0, scalar = 1) {
  tiles.scalar = scalar;
  applyCanvas();
  for (var y = 0; y < canv.height_y; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < canv.width_x; x++) {
      drawTile(tx, ty, x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        Scaler: <input type="number" value="1" min="0" onchange="fillWithScaler(0, 3, this.value)"> <br>
        Anti-Aliasing <button onclick="aa = !aa; this.textContent = aa">true</button> <br>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="256" height="256" style="border: 1px solid gray;"></canvas>
    </body>
    <script src='test.js'></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm reasonable sure that these lines are caused by anti-aliasing. What if you scale the canvas pixels instead?

Comment: thanks! turning ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled to false in applyCanvas() fixes these lines.